# Capistrano + React (create-react-app) + npm - deploy build issue

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy a react application created using create-react-app and am using Capistrano for deployment and Ubuntu server in AWS as a server.

**Versions -**
Capistrano: 3.15
React: 17.0.1

I am getting the below error while deploying into the AWS ec2 ubuntu instance server,

```
.
.
.
00:29 npm:install
      01 /tmp/shopping/nvm-exec.sh npm install --silent --no-progress
      01 Now using node v15.5.1 (npm v6.14.11)
      01
      01 audited 2210 packages in 48.746s
      01
      01
      01 3 packages are looking for funding
      01
      01   run `npm fund` for details
      01
      01
      01 found 0 vulnerabilities
      01
      01
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@IP_ADDR 51.633s
01:21 deploy:npm_deploy
      01  build
      01 /usr/bin/env:
      01 ‘build’
      01 : No such file or directory
      01
 stdout: /usr/bin/env: ‘build’: No such file or directory
 stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@IP_ADDR:  exit status: 127
 stdout: /usr/bin/env: ‘build’: No such file or directory
 stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed:  exit status: 127
 stdout: /usr/bin/env: ‘build’: No such file or directory
 stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:symlink:release => deploy:npm_deploy
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as ubuntu@IP_ADDR:  exit status: 127
 stdout: /usr/bin/env: ‘build’: No such file or directory
 stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   3 packages are looking for funding

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]     run `npm fund` for details

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   found 0 vulnerabilities

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   

 DEBUG [6caec9a2]   

  INFO [6caec9a2] Finished in 51.633 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [141e7887] Running if test ! -d ~/projects/shopping/staging/releases/20210125100109; then echo "Directory does not exist '~/projects/shopping/staging/releases/20210125100109'" 1>&2; false; fi as ubuntu@IP_ADDR

 DEBUG [141e7887] Command: if test ! -d ~/projects/shopping/staging/releases/20210125100109; then echo "Directory does not exist '~/projects/shopping/staging/releases/20210125100109'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [141e7887] Finished in 0.602 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [7e4d0fd0] Running /usr/bin/env  build as ubuntu@IP_ADDR

 DEBUG [7e4d0fd0] Command: cd ~/projects/shopping/staging/releases/20210125100109 && ( export NODE_VERSION="v15.5.1" ; /usr/bin/env  build )

 DEBUG [7e4d0fd0]   /usr/bin/env: 

 DEBUG [7e4d0fd0]   ‘build’

 DEBUG [7e4d0fd0]   : No such file or directory

 DEBUG [7e4d0fd0]
```

Here is my code,

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

group :development do
    gem 'capistrano'
    gem 'capistrano-nvm', require: false
    gem 'capistrano-npm'
end
```

**Capfile**

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require "capistrano/nvm"
require "capistrano/npm"

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
append :linked_files, ".env"
append :linked_dirs, "node_modules"

set :nvm_type, :user
set :nvm_node, "v15.5.1"
set :nvm_map_bins, %w{node npm yarn}
set :npm_flags, %w{--silent --no-progress}

namespace :deploy do
  task :npm_deploy do
    on roles(:app) do
      within fetch(:npm_target_path, release_path) do
        execute fetch(:npm_bin), "build"
        # execute "react-scripts build"
      end
    end
  end

  before "symlink:release", :npm_deploy
end

set :keep_releases, 3
```

Comment: `‘build’

 DEBUG [7e4d0fd0]   : No such file or directory`

Is there a directory named `build`?

Comment: I can able run the "npm run build" command from the server and the root of the application

Comment: @ShivamJha actually i am running the task "npm_deploy" and in that I have "build" command